# UPDATE TOP in Sqlite

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

Is it possible to update first row and with WHERE clause.

I Tried:

```
UPDATE TOP (1) Players SET... WHERE...
```

and:

```
UPDATE TOP 1 Players SET... WHERE
```

But It seems there is no TOP in sqlite.
Can I use some alternative?

 
Or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE Players SET... WHERE... LIMIT 1
```

I can't verify right now, but maybe `LIMIT` only works with `SELECT`statements. If so do this:

```
UPDATE Players SET... WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM Players WHERE ... LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Relying on `LIMIT` on update / delete queries can create some hard to recreate bugs.  I have heard that people use `LIMIT` as a performance enhancement, but I don't think it's worth the hassle.

Comment: @juergend Sorry, but It worked, and then, in second try,  it has stopped, and now UPDATE is affecting everything.
`UPDATE Players SET team='" + All[q] + "', salary='$"+salary+"' WHERE team in (SELECT team FROM Players WHERE team='none' LIMIT 1)`
my query.

Comment: Does your Players table have a unique ID column? If so try something like `UPDATE Players SET team='" + All[q] + "', salary='$"+salary+"' WHERE id in (SELECT id FROM Players WHERE team='none' LIMIT 1)`

Comment: Yes it has, sorry, I will try it.

Comment: Working perfectly, you have saved my life

Answer (score 0):

SQLite does support TOP N queries, but it uses [the LIMIT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) to accomplish this. In any case, that is only for SELECT statements, not UPDATEs. If you want to update just one row, you need to filter the UPDATE using the WHERE clause.

Edit:

I stand corrected, it appears [the UPDATE statement does support the LIMIT clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html).